# DVD m2v to mp4, Anamorphic to Square Pixels, 640x480 or 720x540?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) to convert an NTSC DVD `.m2v` file to an `.mp4`.

The original resolution is `720x480` `4:3` Anamorphic.

I want to convert for playback on a computer using a player like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), with `Square Pixels`.

---

**To preserve the best quality**

Should I convert stretching the height `720x540`?

Or shrink the width `640x480`?

Or should I leave it Anamorphic `720x480`?

---

What is the difference between playing Anamorphic and Square Pixels on a computer monitor?

Does the media player always stretch the pixels to display correctly if Anamorphic?

Does encoding the height stretch from `480` to `540` by FFmpeg improve anything?

---

#### FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg

-framerate ntsc 

-i input.m2v 

-c:v libx264 
-preset medium -crf 18 
-pix_fmt yuv420p 

-s 720x540 
-aspect 4:3 

-vf "fps=24000/1001" 

output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg

-framerate ntsc 

-i input.m2v 

-vf "fps=24000/1001,scale=640x480:flags=lanczos,setsar=1" 

-pix_fmt yuv420p 
-c:v libx264 
-preset medium -crf 18 

output.mp4
```

SAR affects the width only, so the correct behaviour is to modify that. You can leave it anamorphic but a few players may not pay heed to the SAR, so square pixels is safer.

*What is the difference between playing Anamorphic and Square Pixels on a computer monitor?*

Players rescale the video to achieve the SAR-adjusted dimensions. They will usually use a fast bilinear algorithm, so doing it during conversion with a better algo like Lanczos/Sine is preferable.

Comment: Is the required ordering that `-vf` and `-pix_fmt` come before `-c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 18`? And should I apply dithering if scaling to `640x480`? Such as `-sws_dither ed` or `-vf sws_dither=x_dither`.

Comment: The ordering is just a preference to convey the sequence of operations. Default dither is same as `ed`.

Comment: Is a default dither always applied when there is no argument for it?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked. It's true only for higher bit depths. For 8-bit, like here, you'll have to set the flag `ed` manually.

Comment: Should I do that with this scaling or do you think it's not really needed in this case?

Comment: If it's a typical live-action video, you can skip it.

Comment: What is odd is that VLC and mpv player were upscaling the original `720x480` anamorphic video to `720x540` instead of downscaling to `640x480`. It showed in the Codec Information. I thought it should only affect the width, but it was scaling the height. So I was trying to replicate with FFmpeg what the player was doing. Do you know why the players would do that?

Comment: For mpv, it's a [deliberate](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/3948) choice by a dev. VLC's output is strange: for a 1280x720 video with SAR 0.5, it's drawing a buffer of 2560x1440, which is then resized to FHD for me. I'd consider that a bug.